# How to choose which column shrink to fit table width?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with various columns and a fixed width. The premise is that some of the columns should always be fully displayed. So whenever the table's width exceds the container limit a selected column will reduce it's width so the others are not afected.

From this example the desired result would be the first and last column always showing their content while the middle one is shortened to acomplish that.

https://jsfiddle.net/quz7jdk8/1/

```css
#content {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table th,
table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>qnty</th>
        <th>desc.</th>
        <th>total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0.2222222</td>
        <td>weigth product</td>
        <td>255555.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>prod</td>
        <td>1.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Optional: If possible the shortened column should have a `text-overflow: ellipsis;` behaviour.

Additional info I forgot to mention:

- The container width can not be modified under any circumstances.
- No scrolls should be shown since the result will be printed in paper.
- The content of the tbody rows is dynamic. So the problem shows up when the length of the cell's content makes the table larger than the container (like it's shown in the example).

Comment: give your output for better understanding

Comment: you should try `overflow:auto`

Comment: @Bhargav Forgot to mention no scrolls allowed, since the result is for printing purposes

Comment: so increase the div width if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel bad for posting this answer since I still don't understand why it works... I was just trying absurd stuff... sorry for that.

The first part to solve this is to replace the `th` in the header with `td` (th might have some unknown properties that mess everything up). Then set a style to every header cell `width:1%;` except the middle one and the middle tbody cells to `max-width:0;` (don't ask me why or how does it work).

In the updated example you can see what I intended to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/quz7jdk8/5/

So whichever the content is, the first and last column will be always visible while reducing the width of the middle column.

The fact is that it works solid on chrome and firefox.

(obiously if the first_column_length + last_column_length > container_width the intended result becomes imposible)

Comment: Sorry everyone reading this question for all the mess and random sh*t. If someone is able to explain me why does it work or can provide a more legit answer, let me know please.

Comment: Changing a th to a td, is basically just changing the semantic of the table. From a table header to table data. It will change on different browsers but table headers are usually rendered in the middle of the cell and bold where as td have default settings.

In terms of the spacing it's not being controlled by the max-width: 0; it's being controlled by the column header which isn't set using this value.

Due to the overflow property and the ellipsis being set it will still do what is being asked but it's based off the column header as I said, to demonstrate just add more text to that area.

Comment: So, in your opinion max-width to the tbody cell does nothing because it's the header which estipulates the column width... try removing the max-width in the example.
Also, if you add text to the header cell the table will increase its width but if you add max-width to the header cell the desired behaviour hapens again and it's clearly not the original behaviour of max-width:0. We can see it's not 0.

Comment: Yes, if the browser was correctly following max-width: 0; you won't see any of the table cell data. It works the same as max-height:0;. It's just that the table header or td is pushing it's width.

This isn't using a table but a div to demonstrate what happens when these values are applied. https://codepen.io/stefan24/pen/ZJWLON. Play with the width and height values and you'll be able to see more of the content held in the div.

Answer (score 1):

The question wasn't very clear, but I guess you're trying to hide the width of the middle cells at a certain screen width?

But this is a possible solution?

https://codepen.io/stefan24/pen/ZJWYXK

```
            #content{
            border:1px solid;
            max-width:220px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        table th, table td{
            white-space:nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }


        @media (max-width: 1200px) {
            .mid_row {
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                width: 30px;
                display: block;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        }


<div id="content">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>qnty</th>
    <th class="mid_row">desc.</th>
    <th>total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>0.2222222</td>
    <td class="mid_row">weigth product</td>
    <td>255555.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="mid_row">product</td>
    <td>1.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but my problem isn't about the resolution but the length of the cell's content. Still your answer helped me understand what was wrong with my question... editting it right now.

Comment: Okay was a bit vague.
But do you want a column to be a fixed width and then truncate a certain width?

https://codepen.io/stefan24/pen/ZJWYXK

Comment: All cell's data in tbody is dynamic. So even if truncating the middle one the others content can length up making the data not fully visible. The truncating of the middle column should be some kind of dynamic also ensuring the first and last field are always visible whichever the content length is.

Comment: I believe you have all the components to make this solution.
You need to make the width of #content 100% and then set the three columns to 33.33333%. Then set with a break point the width of the centre column with a pixel value and then set the other two to a percentage.

Comment: dude it worked, just check my answer. It's kind of a strange behaviour of the css but it's exactly what I wanted.